# How do I decode strings in my data set? (Each string formatted by '\x' followed by numbers)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, deserialization

I've been collecting historical online comment data from Reddit and putting it onto a Postgres database using Python. I noticed that ~3 million of the 5 million comments appear in an encoded format. Some rows of comments:

```
\x4d524e4120746865206e65772054534c4120f09f9388
\x282028f09f918120cd9cca96f09f918129
\x49206a7573742073656e6420697420746f206d7920706172656e7473206163636f756e74616e74
```

[Here is an screenshot (each row should be a comment of text):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPJYY.png)

I was wondering if anyone would be able to recognize if there was a way to convert these back to their normal string formats in Python.

Comment: These look like hex-encoded UTF-8 strings.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response. That gave me the direction I needed to figure out what was going wrong and fix my data.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Dodd gave me the direction I needed to figure it out. I found some functions that allow me to convert the encoded strings back to their normal format. Oddly, it only worked after I cut out the '\x' at the beginning of each string:

```py
import codecs

str1 = r'\x4d524e4120746865206e65772054534c4120f09f9388'
str2 = r'\x282028f09f918120cd9cca96f09f918129'
str3 = r'\x49206a7573742073656e6420697420746f206d7920706172656e7473206163636f756e74616e74'

str_list = [str1, str2, str3]

for encoded_str in str_list:
    binary_str = codecs.decode(encoded_str[2:], "hex")
    print(str(binary_str,'utf-8'))
```

Comments decoded:

```
>>> MRNA the new TSLA 
>>> ( ( ͜ʖ)
>>> I just send it to my parents accountant
```

Comment: That's the easy one out of the strings above (just ascii characters).  The others look to have some utf8 multibyte sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to brute force decode those strings, assuming they're UTF-8 encoded.

```
import re
if re.match(r'\\x[0-9a-fA-F]*$', line):
    line = bytes(int(line[i:i+2],16) for i in range(2,len(line),2)).decode('utf-8')
```